# rownum and problem with pagination?

Tags: php, codeigniter, count, rownum

I use of `codeigniter` and class `(library) pagination` in it, why after each click on `pagination` in column `#`, `be counted rows from the beginning`.

I want **like** this( p = pagination ):

> p1-> #-> 1 2 3
>
> p2-> #-> 4 5 6
>
> p3 -> #-> 7 8 9
>
> p4 #-> 10

**EXAMPLE:** [see example of my problem](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/show/).
For see **full code** go to here: [FULL CODE](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/196735/)

```
$data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM hotel_submits
        ORDER BY id desc
        LIMIT $offset, 3    
    ) t,
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) r");
```

`Rownum` in top code is the associated with this problem.

You know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you retrieve the `$offset` for the page you are currently on?
Like if I am on page 1, `$offset` = 1,
if I am on page 2, `$offset` = 4 (1 + (page 2 - 1) * 3) 
if I am on page 3, `$offset` = 7 (1 + (page 3 - 1) * 3) 
etc.

If you can't readily get that at the moment, you can pass it from your controller so your view is aware of the current `$offset`.
Then in your code, instead of using `$row->rownum`, add the value of the current `$offset` minus 1 since rownum starts 1.

```
foreach ($results->result() as $row)
{
    echo    '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="true" ></td>';
    // echo    '<td>'.$row->rownum.'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.intval($row->rownum + $offset - 1).'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row->type.'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row->star.' - '.$row->type_star.'</td>';                                
    echo    '<td><span id="'.$row->address.'" class="tooltip">'.$row->address.'</span></td>';
    echo    '<td><span id="'.$row->number_phone.'" class="tooltip">'.$row->number_phone.'</span></td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row->fax.'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row->site.'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row->email.'</td>';
    echo    '<td>'.$row->date.'</td></tr>';
}
```

So on page 2, instead of 1, 2, 3 etc, it should be (1+4-1) 4, (2+4-1) 5, (3+4-1) 6. 
I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `uri->segment(4)`. It should solve your problem. Pagination automatically changes the URI and appends the last count along with the URI. So when you pass `$this->uri->segment(4)`. Then that will take the last value returned so when you move to the next page, you can get from 5 onwards.

This is how Pagination works. So use this:

```
admin/accommodation/show/(segment 4)
```